# How the speed of the i2c communication will be decided that it should be operated at 100kbps or 400kbps rate?

Tags: linux-device-driver, i2c

```
Please clarify above question that i was being asked in interview in one company.

And How slave device will communicate to master if at the same time slave device receives request from two or multiple master?
```

If we have I2C device (Master and Slave connected then how the speed of the data transfer between master and slave will be decided weather to use 100kbps normal mode or 400kbps fast mode)?

Comment: Host should know in advance the lowest speed is used on the bus (device connected). You can't use 400k if you have another device at 100k connected. Host will get this knowledge from device properties (if we are talking Linux: built-in, ACPI, Device Tree).

Answer (score 1):

The i2c slave devices (from a small sensor to cameras in mobile (in cmos cameras, for control interface, not data is i2c interface)) comes with the supported i2c clock rates mentioned in the datasheet. Similarly, the master devices also come with the i2c max. supported clock rates. The speed of slower(from master and slave) will be speed of the i2c communication.

If you are trying to detect the frequency at runtime (i.e. not knowing the supported rate of slave device) is not recommended for embedded devices. (since they are not hot-plug in the most cases).

So, for example the i2c rate is configured 400kHz for master and slave is supporting till 100kHz, then it will be problem. Master needs to configure  <= 100kHz.

If slave supports till 400kHz and master is configured 100kHz (though it is capable of supporting 400kHz), then there is no problem. In this case, the speed is decided according to your speed requirements. If you need more speed (4x speed), then configure the master at 400kHz, and if you are satisfied with the performance at 100kHz, then configure to 100kHz for power saving. You can also configure the master at custom frequency between 100kHz and 400kHz in this case.

If multiple devices with different i2c rates are interfaced on same bus, then the lowest should be the speed. Since it is difficult to change the i2c clock rate runtime in most cases. (e.g. In linux kernel the clock rate and its settings are provided by device tree.)

For multiple master and one slave communication, read [this](http://www.esacademy.com/en/library/technical-articles-and-documents/miscellaneous/i2c-bus/general-introduction/bus-arbitration.html)